# Allow copy-paste into MS Remote Desktop, but not copy from there?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a Microsoft Remote Desktop connecting to a server.

Is it possible to enable copy-pasting from my local computer into the remote windows, but disable it the other way round?

(this way it would be harder to export data from the remote machine)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can disable clipboard sharing in a one-way fashion.  It's either fully enabled (two-way) or disabled.

[image]